# copying data from csv and paste those into another csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two CSV file. and trying to parse datas from file1 and paste those datas to file2. But having some issue to parsing data in file1.

Trying to get `利用額(Fee込み)` row's `全体` But having some issue. With below code I can just parse Company AAA total. Not BBB together...

And when I get those totals, want to insert it file2's this `シリーズFee込金額` row by order...

you can see `.CVS` files here:
[file1](https://ufile.io/c58j3) -- [file2](https://ufile.io/7andc)

By the way there are Company CCC, DDD, FFF too. I just cut those for the quick explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", index_col=0, header=1)

values = df.loc['利用額(Fee込み)', '全体'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[0])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189121/discussion-on-question-by-barbie-copying-data-from-csv-and-paste-those-into-anot).

Answer (score 0):

The column and index of your dataframe is unclear. What is probably most useful is if you set column A and row 2 as your index and column of the dataframe. I would use this to import:

```
df = pd.read_csv("201902.csv", index_col=0, header=1)
```

Then you can use `loc` to index a particular cell. You only need to make one call, using both row and column.

```
val = df.loc['利用額(Fee込み)', '全体']
```

The documentation for [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) might be useful.

If you need to truncate your number (effectively same as throwing away the decimal digits), you can cast to an `int`. Alternatively you could round with `round`. If you need it as a string, cast with `str`.